# Help with understanding Vector3 math

Tags: mathematics, vector

I was making a 3rd person player controller in Unity.

Would

```
Vector3 inputDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;
```

be the same as

```
Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput)
```

?

I'm pretty new to Vectors, and would like help understanding how or how they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression:

```
inputDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput
```

can only equivalent to this:

```
inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput)
```

if `orientation.forward` is `Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` and `orientation.right` is `Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`.

Which I cannot guarantee to be true. Why? Because `orientation` is a variable, and thus it might… well… vary. Using `orientation` allows you to have the input be… well… oriented differently. For example, to make it relative to move a character in a direction relative to where the camera is pointing or to move a vehicule according to its current orientation, and so on.

---

Ok, so you say you want to understand vectors. You need to start with these operations:

- Vector-Scalar product
- Vector addition

---

**Vector-Scalar product**

So, when you have a Vector-Scalar product such as this:

```
v * f
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Vector3(v.x * f, v.y * f, v.z * f)
```

Thus, this:

```
orientation.forward * verticalInput
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Vector3(
    orientation.forward.x * verticalInput,
    orientation.forward.y * verticalInput,
    orientation.forward.z * verticalInput
)
```

And this:

```
orientation.right * horizontalInput
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Vector3(
    orientation.right.x * horizontalInput,
    orientation.right.y * horizontalInput,
    orientation.right.z * horizontalInput
)
```

---

**Vector addition**

If you add two vectors like this:

```
a + b
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
Vector3(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z)
```

So when you have this:

```
Vector3(
    orientation.forward.x * verticalInput,
    orientation.forward.y * verticalInput,
    orientation.forward.z * verticalInput
) + Vector3(
    orientation.right.x * horizontalInput,
    orientation.right.y * horizontalInput,
    orientation.right.z * horizontalInput
)
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
Vector3(
    orientation.forward.x * verticalInput + orientation.right.x * horizontalInput,
    orientation.forward.y * verticalInput + orientation.right.y * horizontalInput,
    orientation.forward.z * verticalInput + orientation.right.z * horizontalInput
)
```

---

**Wrapping up**

So how can

```
Vector3(
    orientation.forward.x * verticalInput + orientation.right.x * horizontalInput,
    orientation.forward.y * verticalInput + orientation.right.y * horizontalInput,
    orientation.forward.z * verticalInput + orientation.right.z * horizontalInput
)
```

Be the same as this:

```
inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput)
```

Well, it implies that:

```
horizontalInput == orientation.forward.x * verticalInput + orientation.right.x * horizontalInput

0.0f == orientation.forward.y * verticalInput + orientation.right.y * horizontalInput

verticalInput == orientation.forward.z * verticalInput + orientation.right.z * horizontalInput
```

And thus:

```
orientation.forward.x == 0.0f
orientation.right.x == 1.0f

orientation.forward.y == 0.0f
orientation.right.y == 0.0f

orientation.forward.z == 1.0f
orientation.right.z == 0.0f
```

Which is how I get this:

```
orientation.forward = Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

orientation.right = Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
```

---

**Learning material**

I'm going to send you to [3Blue1Brown video series on Linear Algebra](https://www.3blue1brown.com/topics/linear-algebra).

*I have written an [Introduction to Vector Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4335556/6928) and [How to Work With Arbitrarily Oriented Vectors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160075/10408) before, which you go over if you rather my writing.*